# Notepad++ Keyboard Language just Changed

Tags: keyboard, settings, notepad++, application-settings

Notepad++ suddenly changed its keyboard settings, which now means it thinks I use a English keyboard, although I have a Nowegian keyboard.

To this end, for instance **shift + 2** becomes **@**, as opposed to **"** whcih it should be.

How do I reset this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Press ALT+SHIFT. That could happen if you try to make rectangular selections...

Comment: in my case I needed to restart notepad++.

Answer (score 10):

in my case, CTRL+SHIFT worked.